# After removing the item from the ListView, ListView is not updated

Tags: android, listview, fragment, simplecursoradapter, notifydatasetchanged

After removing the item from the lvSimple (ListView) I can not update the contents of LisView. The data from the database are removed. Items of ListView too. But i need to "flip through" fragments to see this. It's part of my code.

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        myDB.deleteRow(acmi.id);
        populateListView();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

public void populateListView() {
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_DATE, DBAdapter.KEY_AREA, DBAdapter.KEY_PASSENGER};
    int[] toViewsID = new int[]{R.id.tvItemDate, R.id.tvItemArea, R.id.tvItemPassenger};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myC;
    myC = new SimpleCursorAdapter(view.getContext(), R.layout.item, c, fromFieldNames, toViewsID, 0);
    myC.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex == 1) {
                String createDate = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                textView = (TextView) view;
                textView.setText(dateFormat(createDate));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    lvSimple.setAdapter(myC);
    myC.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lvSimple.invalidateViews();
}
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to be able to see what the problem is. However a common mistake is to remove an item from the DB or a list, but not the list within the adapter. You may have ended up with several copies of the same list. Be sure you remove the one from the Adapter for the listview to update.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to achieve a complex setup with a simple class (SimpleCursorAdapter). Perhaps you could try to extend the cursor adapter in your own class and instantiate that one? That way you can have control over how your data is prepared for the list (and be able to invalidate/refresh or add/remove items easily)